# Rails 4 ActionMailer : is it possible to check the current mail recipient in the mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I am sending a mail with bcc: option, and I would like to include a conditional inside the mailer view based on it. Something like

```
<% unless current_recipient is bcc email %>
    text/links to display
 <% end %>
```

Is it possible to check the current recipient value when you have many in the to: or bcc: mail method options ?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently after some researches, that is not possible."no, that's not possible... when you send an email with a bcc option, you only send a single email, and your SMTP server is responsible for sending it out to both parties (with the BCC address treated appropriately)"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that is not possible.
Gathered from IRC channel this answer :
"no, that's not possible... when you send an email with a bcc option, you only send a single email, and your SMTP server is responsible for sending it out to both parties (with the BCC address treated appropriately)"